# Jenkins Files to archive pattern

Tags: ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In the Jenkins copy artifacts plugins, it follows ant `includes` attributes of fileset.

If I give `Output/**/*`
it copies everything including the `Output` folder.

How can I tell to copy only everything inside `Output` folder but not the `Output` folder iteself.

source: `Output/v2.1/xxx/*.*`

Destination:`v2.1/xxx/*.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, its probably not possible in copy artifact plugin.

But the same objective can be reachable by another plugin, called `Artifact deployer plugin`. In that plugin when you deploy the artifact to local or remote server, you can specify the `base directory`, so the artifact is copied from the base directory excluding the base directory. In this case if I specify my base directory as `Output` then it copies what is inside the output directory.